# How to extract part of a filename in Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel

I saw a post about using the CELL function to return and extract the filename as **ABC.xlsx**.  The formula used was:

```
=REPLACE(LEFT(CELL("filename",A1),FIND("]",CELL("filename",A1))-1),1,FIND("[",CELL("filename",A1)),"")
```

I only want to show **ABC** without the .xlsx filetype extension.  How do I modify the formula to show only ABC?

Answer (score 1):

```
=LEFT(CELL("filename",A1), LEN(CELL("filename",A1))-4)
```

Comment: I believe you meant to delete 5 from the length, as you need to include the ".".  Also, this will only work if the file extension is four letters; if it's a three-letter extension, it'll cut off some of the filename. You'd want `FIND(".",CELL("filename",A1))-1` in place of the LEN part to account for that.